# threadPoolExecutor outOfMemoryException

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

i have a class with a run method , and the timer in the main method of that class is calling the class with this code:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new LegacySmsSender(), 0, 2*1000);
```

in the run method , i declare a ThreadExecutorPool :

```
ThreadPoolExecutor packetProcessorThreadPool =
        new ThreadPoolExecutor(4,
                                4,
                                Long.MAX_VALUE,
                                TimeUnit.DAYS,
                                new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(),
                                new MyThreadFactory("packetProcessorThreadPool")
                                );
```

i create 4 PacketProcessors with `new PacketProcessor()` and  do  `packetProcessorThreadPool.submit` and hold their `Future` returns in a list. Then I wait for all of them to finish in a loop :

```
for(Future<?> f:packetProcessorList)
{
   System.out.println("before f.get() "+new Date());
   f.get();
}
```

And inside those PacketProcessor Class's run methods , they declare a ThreadPoolExecutor and create and submit threads in numbers between 1-5000(its usually creating 6-7 threads) and the threadPoolExecutor code in PacketProcessor is like this:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor commonThreadPool =
        new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                        20,
                        20,
                        Long.MAX_VALUE,
                        TimeUnit.DAYS,
                        new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(),
                        new MyThreadFactory("commonThreadPool"));
```

and in the end , i ran this for some 20 minutes , i check the VisualVM , my memory usage and live thread count rises all the time. What is the problem ?

**Note : Please never hesitate to ask me for more info or questions**

here is the screenshot with some info :

[image]

**edit 1 :**

i took a heap Dump of 270 MB. i found 160mb of char[] . and i found like 1000-2000 thousand query strings.  i build query strings with a StringBuilder. why they dont get GCed ?

Answer (score 2):

Executors are meant to be declared once on application startup and reused. Otherwise you might as well just create individual threads on demand. If you keep creating new executors during application execution, their threads will be left running and so the thread count will keep increasing.

So just create the executors using a DI framework and inject them into your code. Or if it's a small project, put them in a static field.

Comment: i tried using them as static but it didnt change the image on this profiler at all. What is the reason of live threads never decreasing ?

Answer (score 1):

> in the run method , i declare a ThreadExecutorPool

If you declare ThreadExecutorPool in run method that gets executed every 2 seconds you will get many threads in a few minutes.

Comment: no. in the run method , i wait for the threads to finish , so the timer never starts again before the first ran `LegacySmsSender` finishes

Comment: Do you have this code in your run method that gets executed periodically?: ThreadPoolExecutor packetProcessorThreadPool =
        new ThreadPoolExecutor(...

Comment: this code is in the run method of the thing that the timer executes

Comment: Put it somewhere else or do a packetProcessorThreadPool.shutdown(); somewhere. It would be better if you put it somewhere else and create it once like @artbristol suggested

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've told all of the `ExecutorService`s that you create to make threads and then keep them alive forever. This is very plainly obvious in the code:

```
new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                        20,
                        20,
                        Long.MAX_VALUE,
                        TimeUnit.DAYS,
                        new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(),
                        new MyThreadFactory("commonThreadPool"));
```

The third and fourth arguments basically say "keep idle threads alive for (practically) infinity days".

You can solve this in a couple ways:

1. Call `ExecutorService.shutdown` on the executor instances when you are done passing them tasks.
2. The best solution, use a single `ScheduledExecutorService` and a more reasonable task distribution logic to limit the number of threads and drive up performance by preventing thread context switching.

Comment: i tried the solution on number1 , and called `shutdown` on TPEs after i wait for the Future.get s in loops. i got thread execution rejections , then i tried number2 , with 3 and timeUnit Seconds , it didnt change anything at all. Shouldnt the live thread number decrease at some point ?

Comment: If you get a `RejectedExecutionException` then you are submitting tasks to the ExecutorService after it has been shut down. Feel free to read the API. As far as the Threads go, I was mistaken, they will not die until the thread pool is shutdown since they are "core threads".

Comment: with both setting the "keep ide threads alive for 3 seconds" and also shutting down the `commonThreadPool` , now i manage to have 27 threads live at maximum. it changes between 19 and 27. but the memory usage is going up continuously still